# gulp: babelify runs without error, but doesn't transform my node modules

Tags: npm, gulp, babeljs, uglifyjs

I am:

- bundling with browserify
- transforming ES6 to ES5 with babel
- minifying the ES5 with uglifyjs

Which previously worked. However recently I've been getting errors from `uglifyjs` complaining about ES6 syntax, as if babelify hasn't actually run:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {

    // Browserify/bundle the JS.
    browserify({
        entries: './public/js/src/index.js',
        insertGlobals : true,
        fullPaths: true, // For discify
        debug: ! isProduction
    }).transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'))

});
```

**Why isn't `transform(babelify)` transforming the code?**

Please give actual answers, rather than cut and pasted gulpfiles.

Comment: Could you paste your browserify & babelify version? I just ran your snippet on my machine and everything works.

Comment: Also uglify sometimes complain about syntax error because of, you know, actual syntax error, not necessarily unsupported ES6

Comment: @LimH. Yep but I've ran the browserify without the uglify and it's generating ES5

Comment: @LimH. I've already upgraded babelify, looks like it works now. Thanks for your help and sorry it's too late!

Comment: No worries browserify transformers and gulp are not best pals. I rant about them here if you are interested. https://github.com/limdauto/gulp-transformers/ My plugin isn't very reliable yet but hopefully will be.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was using npm modules: [**babel ignores npm modules by default**](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed). So if the modules are ES6, they'll still be in ES6 when uglify runs.

Upgrading babel and using [the `global` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) has fixed things:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {

    browserify({
        entries: './public/js/src/index.js',
        insertGlobals : true,
        fullPaths: true, // For discify
        debug: ! isProduction
    }).transform(babelify, {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            compact: false,
            global: true
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'))
})
```

Another option is to put this in `package.json` in your private modules. Note the syntax is strange, and uses arrays rather than objects to match items to their options:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
       [
         "babelify", 
          { "presets": ["es2015"] }
       ]
     ]
  }
}
```

See the [babelify docs](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed) for more information.

Comment: Yet another option is to add `.babelrc` to the project root, with `{ "presets": [ "es2015" ] }`